# Add language translator in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am purchasing wordpress theme but I want a language translator in it so that user can view the pages in their own language. Any idea how will it be done. I want it for the user not me. I just want it so that my website can be used any person who is not comfortable with english & can convert the page in its own language. Any  idea how much time it will take. Is there any plugin for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) or [WPML](https://wpml.org/) may be what you're looking for.